# If $f_n(t)=f(t^n)$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ to some continuous limit then $f$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Please let me know if my proof is OK. If you have another solution please let me know.

**Problem**

> Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $f_{n} : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
>   $$f_{n}(t)=f(t^{n});\;\; n\in \mathbb{N}$$
>   Prove that if there exists $g : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous such that $f_{n}  \to g$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ then $f$ is constant.

**Proof**

We have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(t)=f(0),$ if $0\leq t<1;$ and   $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(t)=f(1),$ if $t=1.$
Let 
$f_{n}(t)\to g$
uniformly. Since $g$ and $f$ are continuous then 
$$f(0)=\lim\limits_{t\to 1^{-}}f(t)=f(1),$$
as desired.

Comment: You only proved that $f(0)=f(1)$ (and not correctly btw), but this does not prove that f is constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is not correct.

You have only shown that $f(0)=f(1)$, but in order for $f$ to be constant you need to show that
$f(0)=f(t)\forall t\in [0,1]$.

Some more remarks:

- $f(0)=\lim_{t\to 1^-} f(t)$ is not explained why that holds.
- also the limits $\lim_{t\to 1^\pm}$ are not really necessary.
- you should explain where you have used uniform convergence

Comment: New improve:
Since $f_{n}(t)\to g $ so $g(t)=f(0)\; t\in [0,1)$ and $g(t)=f(1)\; t=1.$

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous so $f(0)=\lim_{t\to 1^-} f(t)$

Comment: Also I removed the $\lim_{t\to 1^\pm}$ in my proof because it is not needed.

Comment: Am I need to do more???

Comment: this is the right direction, but you still only have $f(0)=f(1)$ and not the other values. But you know that $g$ is constant, maybe that helps

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is not constant. There exists $t_0$ such that $f(t_0)\neq f(0)$. You have remarked that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f(t^n)=f(0)=g(t)$. Since $f_n(t)=f(t^n)$ converges uniformly, for every $c>0$, there exists an integer $N_c$ such that $n>N_c$ implies that $|f(t^n)-f(0)|<c$. Take $c=|{{f(t_0)-f(0)}\over 4}|$, you obtain that for every $n>N_c, |f(t^n)-f(0)|<|{{f(t_0)-f(0)}\over 4}|$. For every $n>0$, there exists $t_n\in [0,1]$ such that $t_n^n=t_0$ you deduce that $f_n(t_n^n)=f(t_0)=c$, and $|f(t_n^n)-f(0)|=|f(t_0)-f(0)|\geq |{{f(t_0)-f(0)}\over 4}|$. Contradiction.